# Get primary keys with unicode characters in mysql

Tags: mysql, unicode

I'm trying to write an query that will analyze the data stored in Primary Keys across multiple tables to find if they contain unicode characters in them.

**Below are the schema of my tables:**

```
 mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE employee_plain;
+----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table          | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                |
+----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| employee_plain | CREATE TABLE `employee_plain` (
  `emp_id` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `emp_name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `age` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`emp_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |
+----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE employee_unicode;
+------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table            | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  |
+------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| employee_unicode | CREATE TABLE `employee_unicode` (
  `emp_id` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `emp_name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `age` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`emp_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |
+------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Below is the data store on both table. The table `employee_unicode` contains unicode values in the PRIMARY KEY column:**

```
mysql> select * from employee_plain;
+------------------------------+----------+------+
| emp_id                       | emp_name | age  |
+------------------------------+----------+------+
| asdasd123                    | abcsd    |   12 |
| fsoiuioujvsdf4               | abvkd    |   13 |
| sdfgjshgjshdfljsfklju4532489 | sdfsdff  |   11 |
+------------------------------+----------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from employee_unicode;
+--------------------------------------------------------------+----------+------+
| emp_id                                                       | emp_name | age  |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+----------+------+
| A ΠΛΦΟΙΚ ΑΕ#1420000000000000000                              | sdfsf    |   11 |
| sdfsdfsf234                                                  | fsdfsd   |   12 |
| ΑΣΕΛ - ΑΦΟΙ. ΣΕΛΙΔΗ Α.Ε.#000000000000000                     | sdfsd    |   13 |
| ΦΩΤΗΣ#10000000000                                            | sdfsdfd  |   14 |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+----------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**I tried various queries using ASCII, BINARY and REGEX:**

```
mysql> SELECT
    ->   TABLE_NAME,
    ->   COLUMN_NAME,
    ->   COLUMN_TYPE,
    ->   IF( COLUMN_NAME REGEXP '[^\x00-\x7F]', 'Contains Unicode', 'No Unicode') AS Unicode_validation
    -> FROM
    ->   information_schema.columns
    -> WHERE
    ->   table_schema = 'amv_testdb' AND
    ->   COLUMN_KEY = 'PRI'
    -> ORDER BY
    ->   TABLE_NAME,
    ->   ORDINAL_POSITION;
+------------------+-------------+--------------+--------------------+
| TABLE_NAME       | COLUMN_NAME | COLUMN_TYPE  | Unicode_validation |
+------------------+-------------+--------------+--------------------+
| employee_plain   | emp_id      | varchar(100) | No Unicode         |
| employee_unicode | emp_id      | varchar(100) | No Unicode         |
+------------------+-------------+--------------+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   TABLE_NAME,
    ->   COLUMN_NAME,
    ->   COLUMN_TYPE,
    ->   IF( COLUMN_NAME <> CONVERT( COLUMN_NAME USING ASCII), 'No Unicode', 'Contains Unicode') AS Unicode_validation
    -> FROM
    ->   information_schema.columns
    -> WHERE
    ->   table_schema = 'amv_testdb' AND
    ->   COLUMN_KEY = 'PRI'
    -> ORDER BY
    ->   TABLE_NAME,
    ->   ORDINAL_POSITION;
+------------------+-------------+--------------+--------------------+
| TABLE_NAME       | COLUMN_NAME | COLUMN_TYPE  | Unicode_validation |
+------------------+-------------+--------------+--------------------+
| employee_plain   | emp_id      | varchar(100) | Contains Unicode   |
| employee_unicode | emp_id      | varchar(100) | Contains Unicode   |
+------------------+-------------+--------------+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   TABLE_NAME,
    ->   COLUMN_NAME,
    ->   COLUMN_TYPE,
    ->   IF(CONVERT(COLUMN_NAME USING BINARY) <> COLUMN_NAME, 'Contains Unicode', 'No Unicode') AS Unicode_validation
    -> FROM
    ->   information_schema.columns
    -> WHERE
    ->   table_schema = 'amv_testdb' AND
    ->   COLUMN_KEY = 'PRI'
    -> ORDER BY
    ->   TABLE_NAME,
    ->   ORDINAL_POSITION;
+------------------+-------------+--------------+--------------------+
| TABLE_NAME       | COLUMN_NAME | COLUMN_TYPE  | Unicode_validation |
+------------------+-------------+--------------+--------------------+
| employee_plain   | emp_id      | varchar(100) | No Unicode         |
| employee_unicode | emp_id      | varchar(100) | No Unicode         |
+------------------+-------------+--------------+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Please help me understand why I get incorrect results.

Comment: Because you are not looking in the correct table(s) to begin with? Your unicode characters are the _data_ in the column `emp_id ` in the table `employee_unicode`. Whereas you are looking at the column _names_ that `information_schema.columns` provides, for some reason.

Comment: All characters are Unicode. I presume you mean non-ASCII.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If looking for data that contains non-ASCII characters, then compare the stored value to a conversion of that value using ASCII e.g. `WHERE emp_id <> CONVERT(emp_id USING ASCII)`

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
    emp_id VARCHAR(255),
    emp_name VARCHAR(255),
    age INT
);

INSERT INTO employees (emp_id, emp_name, age)
VALUES
    ('A ΠΛΦΟΙΚ ΑΕ#1420000000000000000', 'sdfsf', 11),
    ('sdfsdfsf234', 'fsdfsd', 12),
    ('ΑΣΕΛ - ΑΦΟΙ. ΣΕΛΙΔΗ Α.Ε.#000000000000000', 'sdfsd', 13),
    ('ΦΩΤΗΣ#10000000000', 'sdfsdfd', 14);
```

---

```
SELECT *
FROM employees
WHERE emp_id <> CONVERT(emp_id USING ASCII)
```

| emp_id | emp_name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A ΠΛΦΟΙΚ ΑΕ#1420000000000000000 | sdfsf | 11 |
| ΑΣΕΛ - ΑΦΟΙ. ΣΕΛΙΔΗ Α.Ε.#000000000000000 | sdfsd | 13 |
| ΦΩΤΗΣ#10000000000 | sdfsdfd | 14 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4tmEe3QO)

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE HEX(emp_id) REGEXP '^(..)*[CDEFcdef]'
```

will spot any `emp_id` that has at least one UTF-8 character. (That is, `CHARACTER SET utf8` or `utf8mb4`.)